# Raw specs not building, unknown field

Tags: pallet, chainspec, config, democracy, specs

While building the raw specs:

```
./target/release/kylin-collator build-spec --chain=rococo_democracy.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > rococo_raw_democracy.json
```

I get

```
2022-07-08 16:00:00 Building chain spec    
Error: Service(Other("Error parsing spec file: unknown field `democracy`, expected one of `system`, `parachainSystem`, `parachainInfo`, `sudo`, `balances`, `vesting`, `collatorSelection`, `session`, `aura`, `auraExt`, `polkadotXcm`, `crowdloanRewards`, `ormlTokens` at line 86 column 18"))
```

In the chain_spec.rs, this fields is coded as such:

```
democracy: DemocracyConfig::default(),
```

Node compile is fine as well as the build spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

- https://github.com/Kylin-Network/kylin-collator/blob/d21e1db3511f4536cf234c30d4081da1f4ea1230/node/src/command.rs#L39

```rust
impl IdentifyChain for dyn sc_service::ChainSpec {
    fn identify(&self) -> ChainIdentity {
        if self.id().starts_with("pichiu")
       {
           ChainIdentity::Pichiu
       } else {
           ChainIdentity::Development
       }
   }
}
```

For some reason you're defaulting to `ChainIdentity::Development` which in turn eventually calls [this](https://github.com/Kylin-Network/kylin-collator/blob/3b36bfa7f0fd88f4e2d527857d26ce8334a89715/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L17):

```rust
pub type DevelopmentChainSpec = sc_service::GenericChainSpec<development_runtime::GenesisConfig, Extensions>;
```

And that is the problem because, if you look at the development runtime, there is no democracy pallet and therefore you're getting that error.

Hope that helps!